# Replace sprintf with snprintf with additional parameter

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm writing a shell script, to replace all the occurrences of sprintf to snprintf with one additional parameter in snprintf that is sizeof() in one single .cc file,

Ex -

```
 sprintf(temp1, "msg%d", hostid); 
 sprintf(temp2, "msg%d", hostid);
 sprintf(temp3, "msg%d", hostid);
```

to be replace with

```
 snprintf(temp1, sizeof(temp1), "msg%d", hostid);
 snprintf(temp2, sizeof(temp2), "msg%d", hostid);
 snprintf(temp3, sizeof(temp3), "msg%d", hostid);
```

Note: first parameter of sprintf in this example, could vary to sprintf, it is not constant.

Comment: What if the first argument is a pointer? `sizeof(<pointer>)` will not return what you think it does.

Comment: It is a char array

Comment: In your complete code base? 100% sure? Well then, go for it. Hint: it is good practice to show us what you already have come up with, to improve upon.

Comment: @Christian.K I read "in one single .cc file"

Comment: Yes, and edit that wasn't there when I added my comment.

Comment: @Christian.K  Thanks for pointing out the first argument can be pointer also, I knew that It could be pointer also but mostly it contains char array, I applied the script to the whole file and reverted changes wherever pointer is used in sprintf.

Comment: Just make sure that the places were it is a pointer, you pass the length explicitly (you should know it from the places it is allocated or by the caller passing it).

Answer (score 0):

I think this command will work :

```
sed 's@sprintf(\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\));@snprintf(\1, sizeof(\1), \2, \3);@g' theCCfile.cc
```

Maybe I wrong but I think sizeof parameter have to be same than first `sprintf` parameter no? If not, remplace `sizeof(\1)` by `sizeof(temp)`

In this command, each `sprintf` parameter will be copied to new `snprintf` line. Instead of copy, if you want to replace second and/or third parameter of `sprintf` line, replace `\2` and/or `\3` by constant parameter in `sed` command.

Comment: It was my first stack overflow question and I got the answer in 2-3 mins, @romaric crailox thanks for the script it works.